# git reset failed to change the HEAD

Tags: git

What I have in the work tree

```
* 63a7b9f 2017-08-21 | temp commit (HEAD) [Jiaxiang Liang]
* ad8d3f2 2017-08-19 | adding gitignore [Jiaxiang Liang]
* a562db1 2016-03-31 | revert to correct bugfix [Y. Yan]
* 3b24fd4 2016-03-31 | old src old test [Y. Yan]
* f9b4935 2016-03-31 | old src new test [Y. Yan]
* 6bf6585 2016-03-31 | new src new test [Y. Yan]
* 71209a6 2016-03-31 | new src old test [Y. Yan]
* 3114478 2016-03-15 | bugfix: anti-flow for push pop and peek [Y. Yan]
```

What I want to do is to delete commit `63a7b9f` and move the head to `ad8d3f2`. I don't care about anything in `63a7b9f`. So I did

```
git reset --hard ad8d3f2
HEAD is now at ad8d3f2 adding gitignore
```

It seems to delete the commit, but I have this thing which is bugging me:

```
git status

HEAD detached from 63a7b9f
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So I am wonder why the HEAD is not moving. I do want the HEAD to point to `ad8d3f2`. I want something like after `git reset`:

```
git status
HEAD detached at ad8d3f2
```

Solution: so the answers suggested to use branch gave me some ideas to solve my problem. Notice that I forgot to mention that all of the commits are in status `HEAD detached at <commit>`.

```
git branch temp
git checkout temp
git checkout ad8d3f2 //may not be necessary
git branch -d temp
```

After this, I got my desired status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output `HEAD detached from <commit>` is based on the *reflog* for `HEAD`, not its current value.  This is arguably a bug, but it doesn't mean you aren't on a different detached HEAD now than you were.

Specifically, once `HEAD` is detached, there is no *branch* to reset.  Using `git reset --hard <commit>` simply sets up the index and work-tree while setting `HEAD` *to* that commit, as if you had done another `git checkout -f <commit>`.  `HEAD` *remains* detached; only `git checkout <name>`, for some valid branch name `<name>`, will re-attach your `HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `git reset --hard HEAD^1` ?

Comment: Before you do this command, please checkout your branch with `git checkout your-target-branch-name`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your working tree, it seems you want to delete your last commit. You have several options here, some of which include:

- **git reset** while moving the `HEAD` pointer at the same time. You can do this with

  ```
  git reset --hard HEAD^
  ```

  This will reset your `HEAD` to the commit prior to your last commit, or, in your working tree, commit `ad8d3f2`.
- **git checkout** to a new branch, branching off the second to last commit `ad8d3f2`.

  ```
  git checkout ad8d3f2 .
  ```

  The `.` at the end of the command will apply the `ad8d3f2` changes to the whole working tree. You might run into some trouble if you added files in last commit, because this method won't remove them.
- **git revert**, on the other hand, will remove files if they were added in the last commit.

  ```
  git revert --no-edit HEAD^
  ```

  This is also a good alternative if you don't want to rewrite your commit history or if you've already pushed to a remote repo and don't want to force push—it'll create a "revert" commit instead.